# How to set input value

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a controlled form that looks like this:

```
 const [credentials, setCredentials] = useState<Credentials>({
    username: "",
    password: ""
 });
 const handleChange = (value: string, name: string) => {
    setCredentials(cred => ({
      ...cred,
      [name]: value
    }));
 };
 <Form onSubmit={onSubmit} data-testid="login-form">
      <Input
        value={credentials.username}
        name="username"
        handleChange={handleChange}
      />
      <Input
        value={credentials.password}
        name="password"
        handleChange={handleChange}
      />
      <Button disabled={!credentials.username || !credentials.password}>
        {buttonText}
      </Button>
</Form>
```

`Form`, `Input` and `Button` components are not external UI components and are located in another directory. The `Input` component has the `data-testid` attribute of `form-input`.

This is my test:

```
it("should call handleSubmit in props when clicked", () => {
    render(<LoginForm handleSubmit={handleSubmit} buttonText="button" />);
    const btn = screen.getByText("button");
    const inputs = screen.queryAllByTestId("form-input");
    fireEvent.change(inputs[0], { target: { value: "username" } });
    fireEvent.change(inputs[1], { target: { value: "pass" } });
    fireEvent.click(btn);
    expect(handleSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledWith("username", "pass");
});
```

This works fine but setting inputs like that (firing an `onChange` event on each input) on each test sounds like extra work. Is there a better way out there, or is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: https://testing-library.com/docs/ecosystem-user-event/

Comment: What do you mean by `sounds like extra work`?

Comment: @ksav I realized that these stuff should be handled in `beforeEach` block so that you don't have to repeat yourself in every test. I will post my final result here and close this question.